# Reactjs best practice for updating component depending on url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I was wondering what is the best practice in ReactJS to update a component's content depending on the url.
Let say I have a navbar with some buttons in it. I want to display some of the buttons depending on the url.

For exemple, when the url is `/home` I want my navbar to be:

```
<nav>
     <button>Button 1</button>
     <button>Button 2</button>
     <button>Button 3</button>
</nav>
```

And when it's `/about` I want

```
<nav>
     <button>Button 2</button>
</nav>
```

My main component would be something like:

```
<Router>
    <Header />
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/home">
            <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/about">
            <About />
        </Route>
     </Switch>
</Router>
```

So my navbar is in the `<Header/>` component.
My first guess would be to use `react-router` to get the current url and then change what is rendered in the `<Header/>`

```
render() {
    let buttons
    if(location === "/home") {
        buttons = <button>Button 1</button><button>Button 2</button><button>Button 3</button>
    } else {
        buttons = <button>Button 2</button>
    }
    return (
       <nav>
           {buttons}
       </nav>
    )
}
```

Is it a good practice? Is there a better way? Should I use `react-redux` for the conditionnal rendering? (I'm new to `react-redux` and I'm trying to see all the possibilities)

P.S.: the code is not perfect because I typed it quickly direct in the message box sorry for that.

Comment: I wonder why you even consider the latter when using react router is the better way.

Comment: I am using react-router. I don't understand what you mean by that. React-router has nothing to do with the way I conditionnaly render my component does it?

Comment: Apologies for misunderstanding your question. I think there's no better way than using `Route` in conditional rendering.

Answer (score 1):

you could use a ternary-operator, although there is nothing wrong with the implementation you have right now

```
    import React,{Fragment,Component} from 'react';
    import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom"; 

    class Header extends Component{
     let location = useLocation();
       render() {
        return (
           <nav>
              {
            location.pathname==='/home'? 
             (<Fragment>
              <button>Button 1</button>
              <button>Button 2</button>
              <button>Button 3</button>
             </Fragment>): (<Fragment>
              <button>Button 2</button>
             </Fragment>)    
            }
           </nav>
        )
    }
  }
}
```

and in your main component you could also use `Route` from `react-router-dom`

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
 import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
 import Home from './Home';
 import About from './About';

  class App extends Component{
  render(){
   return(
      <Router>
       <Header />
       <Switch>
         <Route to="/home" component={Home}/>
         <Route to="/about" component={About}/>
       </Switch>
      </Router>
     );
    }
   }
  }
```

Again, this is just a personal preference rather than anything else,but it certainly cleans things up a little

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with what you said. I was just wondering if a better way existed. Thank you